# convert series of json objects to single json object

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which has series of json arrays

```
["FIRST_COLUMN", "SECOND_COLUMN", "THIRD_COLUMN" ...]
["John", "Snow", "Game of Thrones", ...]
["Ned", "Snow", "Game of Thrones", ....]
...
```

but I want one single json object:

```
[
  {"FIRST_COLUMN" : "JOHN", "SECOND_COLUMN" : "SNOW"... } ,
  {"FIRST_COLUMN" : "Ned", "SECOND_COLUMN" : "SNOW"... } ,
]
```

I want to do this in PHP and when I use `json_encode` I get a json but now in the same format, is there a built in function to do this? if not, how can I get the output ?

Comment: Decode it, loop it, build your new object, encode your new object, and call it a day.

Comment: The file you present is not JSON, it rather looks as if each line contained a piece of JSON. Knowing that, you should be able to read it, convert its representation and write it again.

Comment: so use `json_encode` first and then decode it again?

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to with that follow-up question, @overflower. In any case, one thing to do is to try things before asking. People here have little respect for others that want to be spoon-fed solutions to their sometimes trivial homework problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$str = '[["FIRST_COLUMN", "SECOND_COLUMN", "THIRD_COLUMN"],["John", "Snow", "Game of Thrones"],["Ned", "Snow", "Game of Thrones"]]';

//Convert string to array
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

//Remove the first array and store it in a variable
$header = array_shift($arr);

//Loop thru the remaining array
$results = array_map(function ($n) use($header) {
    return array_combine($header,$n); //Combine the arrays
}, $arr );

//Convert array to string
echo json_encode($results);
```

This will result to:

```
[  
   {  
      "FIRST_COLUMN":"John",
      "SECOND_COLUMN":"Snow",
      "THIRD_COLUMN":"Game of Thrones"
   },
   {  
      "FIRST_COLUMN":"Ned",
      "SECOND_COLUMN":"Snow",
      "THIRD_COLUMN":"Game of Thrones"
   }
]
```

---

If your original value is string and not a valid json, you can:

```
$str = '
["FIRST_COLUMN", "SECOND_COLUMN", "THIRD_COLUMN"]
["John", "Snow", "Game of Thrones"]
["Ned", "Snow", "Game of Thrones"]
';

//Convert string to array | Explode by new line and filter.
$arr = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $str),function($e){
    return trim($e) !== '';
});

//Remove the first array and store it in a variable
$header = json_decode(array_shift($arr), true);

$results = array_map(function ($n) use($header) {
    return array_combine($header,json_decode($n, true)); //Combine the arrays
}, $arr );

echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: thanks, I noticed you modified the input, I did a `preg_replace` to convert the newline to comma, and added the brackets, if the data grows larger, `preg_replace` will be slow right?

Comment: Ohh your input is not a valid `json`? I would rather fix on how you put the data there instead of adding `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

You need [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), that's what you need:

```
$keys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age'];
$values = ['John', 'Snow', 27];
$myEntry = array_combine($keys, $values);
// --> ['firstName' => 'John', 'lastName' => 'Snow', 'age' => 27]
```

just `json_decode`, loop through the entries, append the keys, `json_encode`